# Celery creates multiple queues on RabbitMQ -- Non-default queues have no consumers

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using Django Celery with a RabbitMQ backend, all hosted on Heroku.

From the Celery docs, it is clear that Celery is designed to create new queues for tasks.  My problem is, when I go into my RabbitMQ console, I see that only the default queue has any consumers (celeryd instances) hooked up to it.  The result is, all the tasks on the non-default queues never run.

Since the Celery docs explicitly state that Celery is supposed to create many queues, I feel like I must be missing something very basic here with my config.  Nonetheless, I can't get my consumers to 'jump around' and look for non empty queues -- they just stay on the empty default queue.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your celery conf?

Comment: 'jump around' and look for non empty queues? How does that work :)  You have to specify what queues a worker consumes from using the -Q command-line option (or use the add_consumer remote control command)

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem as you, but digging into the docs I think that what happens is that even if the Queue is created automatically, you still need to explicitly tell your Celery workers to start consuming from the newly created queue.

Per the docs, workers are explicitly bound to one or more queues. That is, if you don't specify the -Q argument when you start your worker, it will be bound to the "default" queue, on the other hand if you provide a value to the -Q argument, then it will be bound to those specific queues that you provide. I understand this as to mean that you cannot bind a worker to an "undefined" queue (or a queue that will be created later).

From the docs:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues

It seems that to make your workers start consuming from the newly created queue, you can send a message to them (at runtime) to do so using the add_consumer() method.